# Why is the "english - World" locale not in any way resembling ISO 8601?

Tags: windows-10, locale, date-format, date-formatting, icu

On this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

... it says:

```
2020-01-28T08:17:09+00:00
```

On my computer, running Windows 10, there is a locale called "english - World" (en_001). It's supposed to be some kind of "international compromise" locale, for use when you can't determine the exact locale. This is what it looks like and what I expected based on what I know about international standards/compromises:

***Actual date format:***

```
28/01/2020, 10:17 am
```

***Expected date format:***

```
2020-01-28T08:17:09+00:00
or
2020-01-28 08:17
```

***Actual number format:***

```
123,456,789.99
```

***Expected number format:***

```
123 456 789.99
```

***Actual money sum format:***

```
SEK 123,456,789.99
```

***Expected money sum format:***

```
123 456 789.99 SEK
```

***Actual percent format:***

```
99.99%
```

***Expected percent format:***

```
99.99 %
```

Why is the "World" locale so US-centric and seemingly entirely ignores the ISO standard linked to? It's definitely not supposed to use commas for thousands separators as this is very much US/UK-specific! And Wikipedia specifically states that percentages use a space in international context.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the locale "en-001" is first of all using English, see the prefix "en". And the English-speaking parts of the world does not use ISO-8601-formats but other English-specific "traditional" formats.

ISO-8601 is mainly intended for the technical exchange of date-time-informations. Therefore this standard emphasizes the sortability of date-times in textual form, hence the date-time-components in ISO-8601 follow the order year-month-day-hour(24)-minute-second.

On the other Hand, "en-001" is rather intended for English speakers without exactly specifying the concrete English-speaking country, that means: It can be US, UK, Australia, South Africa etc. Of course, due to the economic and military power of US, the US-standards dominate here.